# Is it okay to instantiate an object in the heap because of the following reason?

Tags: c++

I have a class and the constructor accepts a parameter. For example,

```
class Entity
{
private:
    int number_;
public:
    Entity(int number):number_(number)
    {
       std::cout << "Entity object created";
    }
}

// header
class SuperEntity
{
private:
   Entity *entity_;

public:
   SuperEntity(int value);
};

// source
SuperEntity::SuperEntity(int value)
{
    entity_ = new Entity(value);
}
```

class `SuperEntity` has a private member `Entity`. Since in order to instantiate `Entity` you need to pass in an `int` to it's constructor and cannot be done the declaration file (`superentity.h`) because the `int` value needed to instantiate `Entity` is not available yet, is it okay to dynamically allocate `Entity` in `SuperEntity`'s constructor? Is this a bad practice? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, but you should consider using `std::unique_ptr<Entity>` in this case instead of `Entity*`.

Comment: It seems you are unaware of the *member initializer list*: just make `Entity` a normal member and initialize it in `SuperEntity`'s constructor: `SuperEntity(int value): entity(value) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh: it seems easier to use `std::optional<Entity>` than faffing about with `std::aligned_storage` and `reinterpret_cast`s. Even if you don't want to spent an extra flag you could use a `union` without anything funky.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Wait did I misread this. My bad.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I knew about member initializer list but didn't know it could be used to initialise object this way. Thank you very much! I learnt a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Dietmar remarked, use a *member initializer list*:

```
class SuperEntity
{
    Entity entity_;

public:
    SuperEntity( int value )
        : entity_{ value }
    {}
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I always used member initialiser to initialise member variables but not objects. My fundamental is not so strong.

Answer (score 4):

It is ok per the language but not necessarily the best pratice.

1. Use an object if you can.
2. Failing that, use a smart pointer instead of a raw pointer. See [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).
3. If you must use a raw pointer, make sure to follow [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Answer (score 0):

It's fine to have a pointer data field for a decoupled *has-a* relationship. If you really want to stick to pointers then you should prefer the [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) to raw pointer and utilize the [std::make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) function in the [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) of the constructor:

```
class SuperEntity {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Entity> entity_;
public:
    SuperEntity(int value);
};
SuperEntity::SuperEntity(int value)
    : entity_(std::make_unique<Entity>(value))
{}
```

If you want to have a classic *has-a* relationship abstraction, namely a data field whose lifetime is bound to owners lifetime then loose the pointer and go with the object:

```
class SuperEntity {
    private:
        Entity entity_;
    public:
        SuperEntity(int value);
    };
    SuperEntity::SuperEntity(int value)
        : entity_(value)
    {}
};
```

The `entity_` object will be destroyed once the object of type `SuperEntity` goes out of scope.

Comment: Yes I could use unique pointers. But in my case as mentioned in the other comments and answers its better to use member initialiser list. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Both of the examples use initializer lists.

Comment: Thank you very much mate :)